# Is there anyway to mask your ip other than VPN's and proxies?

Tags: geolocation, ip, spoofing

All i wanna do is spoof my geolocation, but the site I'm trying to reach Blocks any IP that is hosted so VPN's are out of picture as far as Geolocation spoofing is concerned I tried the developer tools on Chrome & Firefox but it doesn't work, the location on [Browser leaks](https://Browserleaks.com) shows my real location. Is there anyway that i can do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You may try Tor browser to protect your privacy. However, some websites do not support tor, so you may need to try and see if that works.

Comment: Well Tor was my second option because the website only accepts request from US so, is there any extension to Tor such that everytime I visit that site the exit Node for Tor request is from USA ?